# Orchard CMS 1.4 Cant upload .avi, .mp4, .flv using Orchard Media

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, orchardcms

I am creating module for video management. I researched everythingand know how to do that, but coped with strange problem. I will use standard Media Capabilities of orchard. I mean i click Media -> Add Media and choose file to upload to server. When i choose .wmv(and other not video formats) all works fine, but then i tried to upload .avi, .mp4, .flv it gives me - Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset. I have tried in different machines and different window(windows 7 and winows 8), in defferent browsers(firefox and chrome), but the same problem.

Please help.

Regards,
Dima.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Orchard but rather with IIS. Does it do that no matter what the size of the file is?

Comment: I am using web matrix so used everything setted up out of the box. I am uploading 5 Mb so size is not big. THe same and even more size i uploaded files ith another extension. If i just change extension of file it ont work too

Comment: Maybe a firewall restriction somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please raise the IIS size limit setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: You are right i tried 3/5 MB and avi uploaed. I thought IIS Have higher limit